# RESTORE_VIEW and RENDER_RESPONSE take too long

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working on a JSF 2 application (primefaces 3.4.1 with Mojarra 2.1.10).
The views are quite big, so the application is not very responsive but it's still acceptable.
It's not a problem when the user displays new data in a form. But it's much more annoying when he just edits data.

We have some simple logic performed (with ajax) when leaving some of the fields:

```
<p:ajax 
        event="blur" 
        process="@this" 
        listener="#{myBean.myMethod()}" 
        partialSubmit="true"
        update="another_component_id" />
```

As expected, when I look at the content of the request/response with chrome developer tools, I can see that only the text field is sent, and only the component referred in "update" is received.
I would expect it to be quite fast, however the RESTORE_VIEW and RENDER_RESPONSE phases take around 3-4 seconds each.
And if I remove the partialSubmit and I set update="@form", much more data is exchanged, but these 2 phases still take the same time.

When looking at this link:
http://www.industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/
I've read that:
"Page performance is largely related to the size of the view tree, regardless of whether the vast bulk of it is excluded from render due to being in non rendered branches.". It seems to confirm my observations but I haven't found much info on this.

Am I correct? Is it normal that even when submitting/updating only part of the page, RESTORE_VIEW and RENDER_RESPONSE are still so long?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is big? What is the size of your JSF code, how heavy includes are used? How much data do you store in view scoped beans? Are view scoped beans serialized (server/client)?

Comment: STATE_SAVING_METHOD is server.
Facelets contain may includes, I can't evaluate the jsf code size. Facelets are generic with loops that depend on the backing beans.
The html is 150 ko. It's mostly primefaces datatables and text fields.
The view contains 250 UIComponent objects.

There is no view scoped beans, most are session scoped. I do not know the session size. 
I do not think it gets serialized, even on the server. Some of the objects are not serializable so I think I would get errors if the server ever tried to serialize the session.
There are few simultaneous users (maybe 5).

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time, performance issues comes from the database and business layer, so the first things is take a look at that part. Now, JSF 1.2 is old compared with the new implementations and a lot of things has happened from that time. Big improvements in JSF 2 like Partial State Saving has solved most of the performance bottlenecks.

Take a look at this article that will clarify your questions about performance [Understanding JSF 2.0 Performance – Part 3 on JSFCentral](http://content.jsfcentral.com/c/journal/view_article_content?cmd=view&groupId=35702&articleId=73398&version=1.8). The code is on [Web Framework Performance Comparison GitHub Repo](https://github.com/lu4242/performance-comparison-java-web-frameworks), so you can take a look at the code and see for yourself where the problem is. I personally recommend [Apache MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/) by its own merits. Compared with action oriented web frameworks like Spring MVC and others, MyFaces does it really great, no doubt about that.

If you want the ultimate performance there is a view pool implementation bundled in MyFaces 2.2, you can try it but third party libraries needs to be compatible with it.

Comment: Thanks. But the original question really focuses on the fact that handling only one field seems to take as much time as handling the whole page.

Comment: It depends of the implementation of the component library, I suppose it happens because you are using something very old, but it should not happen with JSF 2. Some issues has been detected in some versions of Mojarra [See article](http://blog.oio.de/2013/05/16/jsf-performance-mojarra-improves-dramatically-with-latest-release/), it is not as dramatic as the article says, but the problem was big because it decreases the time exponentially. It was fixed in recent versions of Mojarra.

Comment: My bad, I'm using Mojarra 2.1.10 (so JSF 2). I've juste updated the OP